# How to load image and extend it to fit the bound using openlayer 3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm using open layer 3 to load image into layer. Some images are either bigger or smaller than the container size.

How to scale/zoom the images being loaded to fit well inside the container?

I cannot find relating examples from open layer official website.

Thanks.

Comment: Put some code what you have tried. Or see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Same Issue. Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused on your exact question, but you can get an image to fit within certain set bounds inside it's own layer, by setting the `imageExtent`. Here is an example that sets the four corners of an image to a certain position on the map. Is this similar to what you are trying to do?

```
var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
            url: '../images/myimage.png',
            projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
            imageExtent: ol.extent.applyTransform([-121.90, 37.409, -121.89, 37.41], ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"))
        })
    });
```